# What is the meaning of error connection attempt to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed IO::SOCKET::INET bad protocol tcp

Tags: smtp, gmail, command-line-arguments

I simply can't find an answer to why this is happening when I am trying command line attempt to connect to gmail.

I am using sendEmail.exe in a bat file

```
-f xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -t xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -xp xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -u "Test Email" -m "Testing Windows Task Scheduler"  -o tls=yes
```

It is the 'bad protocol tcp' part ia m not finding an answer anywhere.

This is happening only in one sytem. But working on another

Comment: Could you name Operating System you use?  Quick internet search have suggested it may be OS related.

Comment: OS is Windows 7. It is working on some systems which run Win 7. I guess it would be easier to resolve if we know what this error means....

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with other tools and the same purpose. Please, check you have enabled the less secure apps setting on your Google account.

I hope be useful!